# Mysql Query for multi Condition using AND and OR Operator

Tags: mysql

In below query, if I use `OR` then I get results, but which are not correct results, I am choosing values for several select boxes, please tell me solution.

```
SELECT *
FROM stock
WHERE (pro_type LIKE 'CRT monitors')
  OR (brand LIKE 'HP')
  OR (model LIKE 'rew')
  OR (color LIKE 'y')
  OR (processor LIKE 'y')
  OR (cpuspeed LIKE 'y')
  OR (ram LIKE 'rew')
  OR (hdd LIKE 'yy')
  OR (webcamera LIKE 'y')
  OR (screen LIKE 'wre')
  OR (mediadrive LIKE '')
  OR (mediatype LIKE 'y')
  OR (coatype LIKE 'y')
  OR (conditiongrade LIKE 'yy')
```

Comment: What is your `table_schema` ? What result are you trying to get? Please update your question so that the users can understand more.

Comment: show us some sample data, what your currently getting and your expected output.

Comment: If you use `or` and `and` you have to add brackets arround the or conditions. like `field1 ='a' and  (field2='b' or field2='c')`

Comment: Also what is `LIKE 'y'`? in relation to your data?

Comment: in above query i used AND Operator to get results matching with values like 'CRT Montors' and Other values like 'y' from stock table, after running this query i dont get results, but if use OR operator, then i get results.